# getting "java.io.IOException" in MAT?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I had got out of memory exception error.I came to Know that I had a memory leak in my app. Thats why I installed MAT.and I dumped the `hprof` file.

But while opening that .hprof file I got error like...

```
Error opening heap dump 'ind.hprof'. Check the error log for further details.
Unknown HPROF Version (JAVA PROFILE 1.0.3) (java.io.IOException)
Unknown HPROF Version (JAVA PROFILE 1.0.3)".
```

And I had converted the hprof file by using "`hprof-conv fil.hprof file2.hprof`". Its Showing like "`hprof-conv`" command not exists.And I have tried by setting `Hprof` Action to Open in eclipse in DDMS. But its not working.

Comment: please help me I am getting like hprof-conv:command not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution. I used "./hprof-conv file.hprof mat.hprof" instead of "hprof-conv file.hprof mat.hprof"
Thanks

Comment: You didn't mentioned anywhere that you are using Linux.

Answer (score 5):

You have to convert it first in order to use it in MAT.

you can use hprof-conv tool that is located at AndroidSDK/platform-tools/**hprof-conv**

> hprof-conv android.hprof mat.hprof

Then try opening the converted file in MAT.

Comment: Also make sure that the path "AndrodiSDK/tools" is configured in system PATH environment variable.

Comment: You have to install "Android SDK Tools" through Android SDK Manager.

Comment: I had android sdk tools but i am unable to get this hprof-conv command i dont know why?Help me

Comment: Getting ERROR: read 613746 of 1622903 bytes, Please can someone help me. 
Thanks in advance.